# IntentService not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am building an application whereby the notification will ring at a specific time and after which disappear if it is left unattended for 15 minutes. It works when i plug in my device and runs the code. However, once i unplug my device and runs the app, the notification works but it does not disappear after 15 minutes if it is left unattended. Please advice me how should i run the app like how it does when the device is plug into the computer. Also, it should work when the app is killed.

FYI, i'm using notification, alarmmanager, broadcast receiver and intentservice. Below is the snippet of my codes.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Notification(context, "Wifi Connection On");
    Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
    context.startService(background);
}

public void Notification(final Context context, String message) {
// notification codes 

    }

}
```

BackgroundService.java

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

public BackgroundService() {
    super("BackgroundService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   //countdown 15 minutes and cancel notification automatically 
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Dismiss Notification
            notificationmanager.cancelAll();

        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 900000);

}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
<service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
```

Please provide me some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `AlarmManager` instead of a `Timer`. Once your service is done handling the intent, it is destroyed together with your timer.

Comment: hi, im a beginner. do you have an example on how to implement alarmmanger in intent service since i already have one in my mainactivity. @SqueezyMo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service will run twice: first time it does nothing except rescheduling, second time it cancels notifications.

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    private static final String ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFS = "CancelNotifications";

    public BackgroundService() {
        super("BackgroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationmanager.cancelAll();
        }
        else {
            reschedule();
        }
    }

    private void reschedule() {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

        final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
        serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFS);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, REQUEST_CODE, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

In your code, I assume, you start your service with `startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class))`. This intent is passed as a parameter in `onHandleIntent(Intent)`, which means you can access it from inside your service.

Intent allows you to pass additional data, such as action (useful for `IntentFilter`s) or extras. Because you haven't set any, the first time around the execution goes to the `else` branch of `onHandleIntent()` method. `AlarmManager` is then scheduled to run your service in 15 minutes with `serviceIntent`. Note `serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFS)`. So the second time around the execution goes to the `if` branch and cancels notifications.

A better approach would be creating a pending intent right from inside your activity instead of starting a service with `startService`. That would make your service simpler and more cohesive.

Comment: it is deleting the notification immediately whenever it appears instead of 15 minutes later.

Comment: Every time it runs it cancels notifications and reschedules itself. That's why I left that comment. Just pass some additional data in the intent and check whether it's there.

Comment: i dont need it to reschedule itself but i need something like every time the service starts, it adds on 15minutes to the current time and will automatically remove the notification if it is left unattended for that period of 15minutes.

Comment: Like I said, just pass some additional data to distinguish between cases where you want to schedule your service and those where you want to actually cancel notifications. I've updated the answer. A better design would be creating a pending intent from your activity.

Comment: thanks! it worked. do you mind explaining to me what does if (intent != null && ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFS.equals(intent.getAction())) { means? thank you!

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer. I think you could use a good Android tutorial =)

Answer (score -2):

Service only runs when CPU is awake. If CPU gets off, service will not run.

SO to make your service to be run if phone goes to sleep, you need to aquire wake lock.

**BackgroundService class**

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

public BackgroundService() {
    super("BackgroundService");

}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Partial lock permission");

    wl.acquire();
   //countdown 15 minutes and cancel notification automatically 
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Dismiss Notification
            notificationmanager.cancelAll();

            wl.release();

        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 900000);

}
}
```

If this does work out, try to give below permission in Android Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Can you give me the exception from log

Comment: There is an error in BackgroundService line 24. It refers to   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

Comment: I have made slight change in code. Change FULL_LOCK to PARTIAL_LOCK. Try this. Also please import necessary packages

Comment: what are the necessary packages?

Comment: android.os.PowerManager, android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock

Comment: i just tried the codes. It is the same line having error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100241/discussion-between-ijas-ahamed-and-redblackwhite).

Comment: @redblackwhite I had moved power manager initialisation to onHandleIntent function. Try new code